# How can I define a "gradient discontinuous function"?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I am writing a report and need to know how I can define the "kink" in |x|. The function technically adheres to the definition of continuity, and the left and right limits appear to agree here... I need a level of rigor that I can't seem to come up with by myself!

I'm not sure how accurate "gradient discontinuous function" is for describing this function but it's what my adviser and I call it.

Comment: You have studied calculus? yes/no

Comment: Yes, I am a final year undergraduate.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a function $f$ has a kink because $f'$ does not exist at a particular value. In your case, let $f(x)=|x|$, then you can say that
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|h|}{h}$$
does not exist.